# KTable shows the whole event log instead of the most recent update (Kafka Streams)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic with 4 events inside.
Raw topic events:
[topic data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udhTz.png)

The following topology should only print the most recent update to each stock, but it shows the whole log stream.
This is the code:

```
val builder = new streams.StreamsBuilder
val tableData = builder.table[String, StockData](inputTopic)
tableData.toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut[String, StockData].withLabel("table-form"))
builder.build()
```

But the result log looks like this

```
[table-form]: CCC, {"stockVal":10,"times":1234}
[table-form]: BBB, {"stockVal":10,"times":1234}
[table-form]: AAA, {"stockVal":10,"times":1234}
[table-form]: AAA, {"stockVal":20,"times":1240}
```

Why do I get the AAA stock printed twice? All the messages are in the topic when the app is running and so to the best of my understanding I should only get the last value of AAA

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even when the topic is configured as compacted this is the same result. My understanding is that this should create a representation of the topic just as this will produce (this is working)

`stream.groupByKey.reduce( (v1:StockData, v2:StockData) => v2)`

Comment: Compaction only happens on closed log segments. 4 events is not enough to close a broker segment (given: max message default is 1MB and segment size is 1GB)...Printing a stream will always show every event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any table, `table.toStream()` will output its current compacted data, plus any new events into it. It will not dedupe in the logs.

If you always want the current state of the table, then you'll need to iterate its statestore instead.

Keep in mind that the raw topic for the table will also temporarily hold duplicate keys until compaction occurs.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that the best way to get the most recent representation of the stream, compacted by key (where the latest even related to key AAA "overrides" the first one), is by using `toTable` and querying the stream?
This is somewhat strange, the documentation suggests that toTable().toStream() should generated a dedupped version
https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/kafka-streams-convert-to-ktable/confluent.html for example

Comment: It does not say that exactly - see "_Kafka Streams flushes the cache when either the cache is full (10G by default) or when Kafka Streams commits the offsets of the records processed. In this case, when the Kafka Streams flushed the cache, you only have one record for each key_"